# How to get a count of emails in outlook sorted by category and by date replied

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook

I am looking to do two things in outlook/excel.

1. Get a count of the number of emails in each color category. (the color corresponds to who answered the email.)
2. Within each category/person, I want to know how many email responses were made on each day.

[Example of what I am looking for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxQBI.png)

I am not very proficient in VBA but I can maybe figure it out if I had step by step instructions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite know much about Excel and VBA. But from the perspective of the Outlook client, we could get these information by modify our view settings.

You could change your Outlook view to single or preview and set the arrangement as categories.
[image]

And got the count like below.

[image]

If necessray, you could also add filters to filter the email messages you need.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, that by doing so, it resets your view. After having tinkered with the resetted view, I noticed, that it is dependent on the with of the inbox pane (folder content pane). Apparently, the count of emails is only shown, when the central pane is wide enough. I was able to make the email count appear and disappear, just by narrowing or widening the central pane.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).